# Outputting the name of the month instead of the number

Tags: php, sql, mysql, conditional-statements, if-statement

I have a query which returns 3 fields, one of which is the month as a two digit number.

I want to basically have it so if month == 1 output january, if month == 02 output febuary etc

This is what I am trying, but this does not work at all, and prevent the entire column from being displayed in PHP.

```
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sqlstr)) {
               if ($row['theMonth']=="6") {
                  echo "<td>{June}</td>";}
                  echo "<td>{$row['sumSales']}</td>";
                  echo "<td>{$row['sumPurchases']}</td>";
                  echo "</tr>";
               }
            }
```

What is the correct way to do what I want, and why is what I am doing wrong?

The SQL query I am using is:

```
SELECT theMonth, sum(Sales) as sumSales, sum(Purchases) as sumPurchases
FROM
 ( SELECT date_format(saledate, '%Y-%m') AS theMonth, sales.cost as Sales, 0 AS Purchases
   FROM sales, products
   WHERE sales.product=products.name AND category='Food' OR category='Bocas' 
                OR category='Bebidas' OR category='Flor de cana por botellas' 
                OR category='Vino por botella' OR category='hora feliz'
  UNION ALL
   SELECT date_format(purchasedate, '%Y-%m') AS theMonth, 0 as Sales, purchases.cost as Purchases
   FROM purchases
 ) AS all_costs
group by theMonth
```

I don´t think I could just replace

```
SELECT date_format(purchasedate, '%Y-%m') AS theMonth
```

with

```
SELECT MONTHNAME(purchasedate) AS theMonth
```

So what would be the best way to return the month name as text in SQL?

Comment: Why don't you think you can use `SELECT MONTHNAME(purchasedate)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your SQL you can use [`DATE_FORMAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) to convert a date to a month name:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%M')
```

```
July
```

The list of allowable specifiers can be found in the MySQL documentation.

([MONTHNAME](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_monthname) should also work too.)

The reason why your current method doesn't work is because you are currently outputting both the year and the month (e.g. "2010-06") and this string doesn't compare equal to the string "6".

Answer (score 1):

First option would be to modify your SQL query to return the month as a name rather than (or as well as) a numeric. See [MONTHNAME](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_monthname)

Second option would be to use PHP's date functions to generate the name for you

```
$monthName = date('F',mktime(1,1,1,$row['theMonth'],1,2010));
```

Third would be to use a monthnames array, similar to zebediah's suggestion

Answer (score 1):

.

```
function month_name($int) {
  return date( 'F' , mktime(1, 1, 1, (int)$int, 1) );
}
echo month_name(2); // February
```

Answer (score 0):

There is probably a php builtin for that, but not using anything like that

```
$monthNames = array(1 => "January", 2 => "Febuary", 3 => "March", .... 12 => "December");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sqlstr)) {
    echo "<td>{$monthNames[$row['theMonth']]}</td>";
    echo "<td>{$row['sumSales']}</td>";
    echo "<td>{$row['sumPurchases']}</td>";
    echo "</tr>";

}
```

Comment: assume you mean: $monthNames = array(1 => "January", 2 => "Febuary", 3 => "March", .... 12 => "December");

Comment: *facepalm*  I checked the manual to see if it was , or ; ... but then forgot about the declaration.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You've got a closing curly brace at the end of the line on your first `echo` statement. That's  causing PHP to prematurely terminate the conditional block, then it has a parse error when it stumbles across your last closing curly brace since it doesn't have an opening match.

You can get the name of the month from a timestamp (if you have one) with the date function. `date('F', $timestamp);` [see the php date function reference](http://php.net/date)

Doing it in the SQL statement is probably your easiest and most performance-friendly way of handling this particular situation.

Comment: I missed the closing curly brace when I edited the question to format the code as code, so I'm probably to blame for that